# Correct usage of the verb 'told' in the sentence "I did it the way he told me to"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

I'm trying to learn how to use the auxiliary verb *did* in sentences. I stumbled upon this [webpage](https://www.wordscoach.com/blog/how-and-when-to-use-did-with-daily-use-sentences/), which has a few sentences enlisted with the correct usage of the word *did*. One of those sentences is *I did it the way he told me to*.

I read the rule **the verb that follows did should be used in its base form.** on [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form#:%7E:text=The%20auxiliary%20verb%20(did)%20is,is%20shown%20in%20the%20auxiliary.). Now, my understanding is that according to this rule, the verb **tell** should have been used in its base form in the sentence rather than its past form, i.e., **told**.

I'm sure I'm missing some grammar rules I'm unaware of. I need your help to fill me in on those rules.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Britannica.com and your initial webpage example are showing two different things. "Did+main verb" (*did* as auxiliary verb) is a different construction than "I did it the way he told me to" or "I passed the exam and so did Tom." In both the latter examples, *did* is a main verb and *told* / *passed* are independent.

Comment: 'Follows immediately' _not_ '3 pages / 10 words later', Kartik!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "did" is *not* being used as an auxiliary verb. The verb "do" has another, separate meaning: it can be an ordinary verb, meaning "to perform an action."

Comment: Even when the question and answer are trivial, you should try to provide a reference and example.